# How can I implement this on asp.net or asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

Me and my team are creating a portal on asp.net mvc.
We want to create such an url for the users page : http://user.portal.com/ .
How can we implement this in mvc or just asp.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here
http://blogs.securancy.com/post/ASPNET-MVC-Subdomain-Routing.aspx